# PowerShell Set-MSolUserLicense

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

I am trying to unassign a bulk of user's licenses from our Office365.

I have all of the user's UserPrincipalName on a CSV file like so:

```
Name
user.name@domain.com
user.name2@domain.com
"
"
```

That is what I tried to do:

```
$csv1 = import-csv | select -expandProperty name

Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $csv1 -RemoveLicense "domain:STANDARDPACK"
```

---

When I had only one user on the CSV file, **it works**!
But when I try to add more users to the exact file and in the exact same list, the command fails and give me this error:

```
Set-MsolUserLicense : Unable to assign this license because it is invalid. Use the
Get-MsolAccountSku cmdlet to retrieve a list of valid licenses.
```

I doubled checked and made sure the it is indeed the correct license (`domain:StandartPack`)

What else can I do? How can I make it work?

Answer (score 4):

You need to iterate each line in the csv at a time, at the moment you work with all of them at once, so try this:

```
$csv1 = import-csv | select -expandProperty name
foreach ($upn in $csv1)
{
Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $upn.Name -RemoveLicense "domain:STANDARDPACK"
}
```

**EDIT:

Try the following method as well (update if necessary)

```
$csv1 = import-csv | select -expandProperty name
foreach ($upn in $csv1)
{
$License = Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $upn.Name | % {$_.Licenses.AccountSkuId}
    if ($License) {
    Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $upn.Name -RemoveLicense $License
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,I tried that but i still receive this error:  

 Set-MsolUserLicense : Unable to assign this license because it is invalid. Use the Get-MsolAccountSku cmdlet to
retrieve a list of valid licenses.

Again, I made sure that the licesne is 100% is the currect one

Comment: I did and made sure it is the correct license. When I do it for one user it works just fine. But when I try with the CSV it fails.

Comment: do `foreach ($upn in $csv1) {Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $upn.Name | Select UserPrincipalName }` do you get all the results/users? any errors?

Comment: When I run this, I manage to get all the users and their license status.

Now, when I try to change the script block to this:
Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $upn.Name -RemoveLicenses "domain:ENTERPRISEPACK"

I receive the same error: 
Unable to assign this license because it is invalid. Use the Get-MsolAccountSku cmdlet to
retrieve a list of valid licenses

Answer (score 0):

You will need to iterate through all of the licenses assigned and find the one you are looking to remove.

```
foreach($UPN in $csv1){
  $user = Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $UPN
  $license_Count = ($user.licenses).count

  for($e=0;$e -le $license_Count - 1;$e++){
    if($user.Licenses[$e].AccountSkuID -eq "domain:STANDARDPACK"){
      Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $user -RemoveLicenses "domain:STANDARDPACK"
    }
  }
}
```